# Creating the signature in the driving pattern of a vehicle.

Tags: algorithm, hash, signature

I would like to create the signature in the driving pattern of a vehicle. I have collected the readings and plotted the data in 3D, by considering "time" co-ordinate in X axis, while "latitude" and "longitude" in the other two axis. It's very important that I need to follow time axis and take the other two numbers and compress it, just like hashing. Any suggestion or ideas, where can I start up with?

Comment: Can you more info to it or can you explain it more briefly about it, considering me as a layman. Actually you can have a reference as this post [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18210355/how-to-create-a-signature-in-3dimension?rq=1] to understand bit more of it.

Answer (score 1):

The driving pattern of a vehicle is nothing but the trajectory of the vehicle. Let's say its a triple (lat, long, time). Since you want to create a signature out of it I can suggest two approaches:

1. You can consider your entire space as a big cuboid (0,0,0) to (M,N,t_max). M and N are the max lat and long resp., while t_max is the maximum time you are considering. You can now take some granularity and divide your grid into fine and smaller cuboids each of which is small and manageable. You can then use some standard space filling curves like Z-order curve (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-order_curve) or Hilbert curve (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert_curve) to map your 3 dimensional data to a single dimension which is just a linear ordering or a "signature".
2. You can first linearize the ordering of the two dimensional data (lat, long). Once you have done this, you can use the Piecewise Aggregate Approximation (PAA) technique mentioned here: A Symbolic Representation of Time Series, with Implications for
   Streaming Algorithms (dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=882086‎).